# Mathematical explanation for image edge detection and denoising

Tags: signal-processing, image-processing

I am trying to understand why the convolution kernel, $$\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
-1&-1&-1\\
2&2&2\\
-1&-1&-1
\end{array}\right]$$ detects the edges in an image. If anyone has a mathematical reason for this, please post it. Thanks.

Also, why does the a $3$-by-$3$ matrix of $1/9$ work for denoising?

Comment: For your second question, the 3-by-3 matrix of $\frac{1}{9}$ does averaging, and you may think that as a low-pass filter to filter out or average out image noises.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do understand the averaging; If possible could you elaborate though - why does that specific matrix work for virtually any noisy image? Why not say a 3-by-3 matrix of 1/3 for example?

Comment: I presume the above only detects edges in one direction?

Comment: @user98592 $\frac{1}{9}$ is better because this convolution does not increase overall magnitude/amplitude/value/intensity (I don't know the right word for this...). Think of performing this convolution on a large array of $1$'s, you would not wish to make the image brighter (for example, if we are talking about brightness) after denoising.

Answer (score 2):

The convolution with matrix $\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
-1&-1&-1\\
2&2&2\\
-1&-1&-1
\end{array}\right]$ gives a low value on a more even region of an array, and a high value if there is a large difference between that point and the previous or next point in vertical direction. You can try to perform a convolution on an array with horizontal edge like

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1\\
\end{array}\right]$$

Around the horizontal edge, the convolution gives a higher absolute value than in the more even area. As @copper.hat pointed out, this convolution detects better for horizontal or almost horizontal edges, but not vertical edges, as this convolution kernel does not calculate differences between columns.

---

For your second question, the 3-by-3 matrix of $\dfrac{1}{9}\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1&1&1\\
1&1&1\\
1&1&1
\end{array}\right]$ does averaging, and you may think that as a low-pass filter to filter out or average out image noises. $\frac{1}{9}$ is better than other values like $\frac{1}{3}$ because this convolution does not increase overall magnitude/amplitude/value/intensity (I don't know the right word for this...). Think of performing this convolution on a large array of $1$'s, you would not wish to make the image brighter (for example, if we are talking about brightness) after denoising.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of different ways to detect (horizontal) edges. The simplest way is to use the kernel $\left[\begin{array}{r}
1\\
0\\
-1
\end{array}\right]$, which approximates the y-derivative. High values in the result of the convolution with this kernel will correspond to horizontal edges.

The convolution with matrix $\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
-1&-1&-1\\
2&2&2\\
-1&-1&-1
\end{array}\right]$
is a different way to detect horizontal edges. It approximates the second derivative the y-direction. Convolution with this kernel will give you a positive value on one side of the edge and a negative value on the other side. Then you can look for zero-crossings, which allows you to localize edges with sub-pixel accuracy. You can also generalize this approach to detecting edges of any orientation using the Laplacian.

Here is some more information on [using the zeros-crossing of the Laplacian for edge detection](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/zeros.htm).